# View people in a dynamic distribution group

Tags: exchange-2010, distribution-lists

Ok, so I've been dealing with this for a while and I'm sorry if it seems like I'm asking the same question over and over (it sure feels like I am)

Is there a way for my users to run the LDAP query that populates a dynamic distribution list from their machine to see a kind of 'preview' of the members in the group before sending their email to that list?

Answer (score 1):

When I include a distro group in an email using my outlook 2010 client, I get a little plus sign next to the group name. If I click it, it will expand to all the users in that group. Also outlook 2010 will let you browse the members of the group by mousing over the group name and then dropping the group member arrow down.

Comment: for a standard distribution group, this is the case. I'm looking for the members of a dynamic distribution group that doesn't actually get created until the email hits the Exchange server. There is no option to expand the members of a dynamic distribution group

Comment: gotcha. I found this article - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232019.aspx - with a PS 2 liner